# MATLAB, how to make a rlocus for a MIMO system?

Tags: matlab, input, output, feedback

I have a MIMO system (2x2ss) and I want to make a rlocus plot considering both channels (feedback the first output with the first input and the second output with the second input). Since the rlocus works only for SISO system, I cannot manage to solve the problem. Has anyone some idea about it?

Comment: I don't have the full background of control engineering, so I don't fully understand the background of your question. Is this question just about visualization? So calling `rlocus` twice you get two plots and you just want it to be in one figure?

Comment: No, I would like to make a MIMO rlocus in the sense that the varying K has to feedback two channels simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The adequate mathematical tool is [Gersgorin bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). This is a graphical method to check stability of a MIMO system. I found a [paper about controller desgin using Gershgorin bands](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/28493/files/GKL_IFAC.pdf) Maybe going through the paper will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However I eventually make my own MIMO rlocus by modifying the controller as desired at every loop of a for cycle...

Comment: What's you exact aim? Did you notice the [MIMO robustess analysis of Matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/help/robust/gs/multiinput-multioutput-robustness-analysis.html)?